# Is there a way to make NUXT.JS work without having 'unsafe-inline' in my CSP header?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, https, http-headers, nuxt.js

How can I configure Nuxt.JS in a way that I don't need to be adding 'unsafe-inline' to my 'script-src' and 'style-src' CSP parameters?

I am getting the following errors at page load:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at eval (“script-src”).
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“style-src”).
```